# i am using html2pdf.js, if i add local image url in webpage, its not generating any thing, any possible solution?

Tags: html

I am using html2pdf.js,  if I add the images  to the Webpage from the local URL, it's generating nothing.
and showing below as info
My requirement is that a single HTML page embedded javascript should be there and trigger based on button click.
any example code is appreciated.

`0ms html2canvas: html2canvas $npm_package_version`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. You have to write some code yourself and then ask a question if you’re stuck. You can’t ask people to write code for you.